Subscribers for 2GP
Our 2GP recently passed the security review and the managed package is now on the AppExchange. I want to be able to push new versions to our customers.
I provided a customer who had the pre-AppExchange version the installation URL for the latest approved version. They successfully upgraded.
When I navigate to the License Management App in my PBO, I do not see that customer listed in the Subscribers tab. Prior to the installation, I setup a record for the Package and Package Version.
My mental map was that the upgrade process would register my Subscriber. Is this not correct?
I also tried to go to the Package record and select "Refresh Licenses" but got...
Invalid all package id: 0Ho...
Error is in expression '{!doRefresh}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page sflma:licenserefresh: (System Code)

An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (sfLma)


For 1GP you have to request enablement of push upgrades via a partner support case (I suspect you do with 2GP too). As to why you don't see the subscriber detail, have you already installed the LMA on your PBO? (I don't know if this is a prerequisite, TBH, just asking.)

Hi @PhilW - thanks for responding. Yes, we have the LMA installed on the PBO. In it, I setup the Package, Package Versions, and Licenses. I then did the "Refresh Licenses" on the Package but got the error.
